# Cordova File Plugin does not fire deviceready and the content src is a remote URL

Tags: cordova, remote-access, cordova-plugins

As the title says, when adding the cordova-plugin-file to my cordova Android project, the deviceready event is not fired.
  I am also using a remote URL as my starting point, so in `config.xml` I have `<content src="http://www.example.com"` . When I use the default `index.html`, it works.

So is there a problem with the File Plugin Cordova and loading a remote URL?